# JFrog CLI: How can I set or delete a property whose name or value contains equal signs, commas or semicolons?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

From [Setting Properties on Files](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/setting-properties-on-files), I see that the JFrog CLI `jf rt set-props` command uses  an equal sign to specify a property name/value pair, semicolons to separate multiple name/value pairs, and commas to separate multiple values within a name/value pair:

> **Files properties** The list of properties, in the form of key1=value1;key2=value2,..., to be set on the matching artifacts.

So how do I set properties whose names or values contain equal signs, semicolons, or commas?

Similarly, the `jf rt delete-props` command uses commas to separate property names.  So how do I delete properties whose names contain commas?

Comment: @yahavi, Tagging you since you seem to be JFrog Artifactory expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only properties with special characters in their values can be set.
Artifactory does not allow special characters in property names:

> The following special characters are forbidden in the key field:
> )(}{][*+^$/~`!@#%&<>;=,±§ and the Space character.

Use the `\` escape character to set a property with a special character in the value. As an example:

```
jf rt set-props "name=val\=ue"
```

Read more about it:

- [Artifactory REST API](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/set-item-properties)
- JFrog CLI documentation:

  - [Set props](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/setting-properties-on-files)
  - [Delete props](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/deleting-properties-from-files)

Comment: Thanks @yahavi.  I'll give your answer a try later today.

Comment: I've found some strange results.  Escaping a semicolon in a property value does seem to work in the I get the following in the search results:

```"props": {
      "name": [
        "val;ue"
      ]```

But when I view the properties in the Web UI, it shows that the **name** property has two values, **val** and **ue** rather than the single value **val;ue**.  Is this a bug in the UI?

Comment: @yajavi Do you know if my previous comment is a bug?  Is there an "official" way to open possible JFrog bugs?

Comment: For UI issues you can reach out to the JFrog support